# How to secure ASP .NET WebAPI 2.0 multitenant app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My task is to build multitenant ASP .NET WebAPI server (hereinafter SERVER) that will expose its routes to multiple SPA client-side apps (hereinafter APPS).

Let's say there's a route '/api/tasks' (hereinafter ROUTE) and list of authorized apps on server-side. The list contains APP A and APP B. Both APPS are JS SPAs.

Having that said, constraints are as follows:

1. When APP A will call the ROUTE, it will return only resources avaliable for APP A.
2. When APP B will call the ROUTE, it will return only resources avaliable for APP B.
3. When non-registered APP C will call the ROUTE, it will get 403 response.
4. There's of course no way for APP A to reach resources of APP B.

In other words, when tere are resources intendet to serve for APP A, that is, let's say a website, there's no way to reach them from any other website (or app). It's not about role-based authorization or any kind of human-driven auth. It's about website having access to particular portion of data just by being a particular, specific website.

Another constraint is that the APP should be client-side only JS SPA or have as little of server-side implementations as possible. Server-side rendering unfortunately is not a case.

I've found several of scenarios for similar cases in the Internet but none of seems to meet these requirements.

I need at least a hint or general guideline on how should I approach this problem.

Comment: Each app sends a Guid corresponding to their registration which identifies what all resources are available.

Comment: When it's only client-side SPA then Guid is easily retrievable from open code. So this is not really secure solution. One can easily get this guid and put it in another app and then constraints given above won't be met.

Comment: You may have better luck posting to http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you're finding little information because this isn't a good way to go about things. From what I can tell you want to identify permissions by device or installation instance? What happens when that device gets lost and found by someone who shouldn't have access, or someone leaves their laptop unsupervised for a period of time?

You need to verify that the person using the app should have access, the way to do that is through accounts based authentication.

Comment: No, no, it's clearly a misunderstanding. Let's say that the APP mentioned in my question is simple blog or just a landing page. This app's main page fetches data from the SERVER but apparently it's not required to be signed in to access this area. I just want to make sure that this data can be accessed ONLY from APP's main page. 

It's obvious that some kind of app-key solution would work here, but I have no idea how to make it secure with none or only minimal server-side implementation on APP's side (which in most cases will be represented as simple SPA).

Comment: Ahh, ok - If it's an SPA, it's still hosted on a secure server somewhere, can you not just keep the guid on that? like in app-settings in web config? It would help if we knew what platform the spa is

Comment: In the past I've had one central users table, and multiple different web apps that use it for authentication. Some users don't have access on certain apps so the solution was to pass in a web app id with login and confirm in the db server side that they have access for that web app. Just store the app id in the web config, if your server is secure then it won't be visible to people client side

Comment: For now most propably it's be cloud-hosted VueJS app. I have no idea how to pass app-key to the SERVER with every single query without risk that app-key will be revealed. If it is the same solution that you wrote about, of course.

Comment: Instead of sending the Guid via query string, send in post... And over a secure channel so no One can see it

Comment: @NitinSingh I can see whats sent in a post quite readily in dev tools, it's how we debug problems?! I think he doesn't want anyone to see the key. Even current user

Comment: At the end of the day vueJs still needs to be hosted somewhere so just put the key on that server. But that's a different question altogether